# cannot access ubuntu server behind huawei router even after port forwarding

Tags: home-server, port-forwarding

I have an ubuntu 12.10 server installed, got a static ip from my ISP. Pinging the ip results in success. I also have a huawei Echo-Life modem. Following [this site](http://portforward.com/) I was able to set the ports to be forwarded. I also checked this with the guys at huawei. The problem is that when I enter my static ip in the browser, I always get stuck at the modem/router login interface.

Going to the ip address assigned to my ubuntu server (on my network) I can see that nginx serves pages correctly. Another thing is that getting my modem/router interface is only possible via my local network. I asked a friend to try my static ip but he said he got a blank page. I think this means that the gateway is not accessible from the outside world.

I think I'm missing something minimal here as it's not supposed to be this complicated setting up a home server. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The huawei router does not support [loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback). This means that when you use the WAN address of your router from the LAN side you get the LAN address instead. Your router setup page is connected to LAN:80 and your forwarding is done from WAN:80